# Autogrowing list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I need a list-like object that will "autogrow" whenever a slot number greater or equal to its length is accessed, filling up all the newly created slots with some pre-specified default value.  E.g.:

```
# hypothetical DefaultList class
x = DefaultList(list('abc'), default='*')
x[6] = 'g'
print x[2], x[4], x[6], x[8]  # should print 'c * g *'
```

Thanks!

PS.  I know it is not hard to implement a class like this, but I avoid wheel-reinvention as much as possible, especially if a particularly efficient/well-designed wheel already exists.

PS2.  A dict (or a collections.defaultdict) is *not* an acceptable implementation of the desired data structure.  For why, see here: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/bcf360dfe8e868d1?hl=en

Comment: so if someone makes a new collection, places something in slot 1 then in slot 1,000,000 you end up with 999,998 useless objects taking up memory? sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: maybe it would suffice, if you keep your added items in dict, and to keep the default value - members not changed won't have to be kept in memory at all.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but given your link isn't your issue more with the interface of collections.defaultdict rather then using one as an implementation?

Comment: I don't see an argument against using `dict`s as the backend in the link -- as long as the interface is `list()` compatible, why does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class DefaultList(list):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        list.__init__(self,*args)
        self.default=kwargs.get('default',None)
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        # retrieving an item does not expand the list
        if isinstance(key,slice):
            return [self[elt] for elt in range(key.start,key.stop,key.step)]
        else:
            try:
                return list.__getitem__(self,key)
            except IndexError:
                return self.default
    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        # setting an item may expand the list
        try:
            list.__setitem__(self,key,value)
        except IndexError:
            self.extend([self.default]*(key-len(self)))
            self.append(value)

x = DefaultList(list('abc'), default='*')
print(x)
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
x[6] = 'g'
print(x)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', '*', '*', '*', 'g']
print x[2], x[4], x[6], x[8]  # should print 'c * g *'
# c * g *
print(x[2:9:2])
# ['c', '*', 'g', '*']
```

Comment: This is reasonable; a couple notes.  You should use `super` rather than addressing the parent class directly.  `None` is probably a more sensible `fillvalue` default than `'*'`.  You should pass `kwargs` to `list.__init__`, so keyword arguments work, eg. `DefaultList(sequence=[1,2,3])`.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: I think using `super` here would actually lead to a subtle pitfall. Since `DefaultList`'s `__init__` signature is different than `list`'s `__init__`, I can't use `super`. `super(DefaultList,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)` would raise a TypeError since `list.__init__` expects at most 1 argument. I like the idea of using `None` as the default.

Comment: (That's not related to `super`.)  You want to make a copy of kwargs (`kwargs=dict(kwargs)`), and remove "default" if it exists after pulling the value out.  This way it's as transparent as possible with arguments, so things don't go wrong if this class is used with more complex inheritance.  (It's simpler to just make `default` a regular keyword argument, but that can only be done correctly in Python3 which supports keyword-only arguments via PEP 3102.)

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: In a more complex inheritance scheme, if another class expects the `default` keyword, removing it in `DefaultList` would be wrong. Since we don't know what class's `__init__` is going to be called by `super(DefaultList,self).__init__`, the only safe option is to demand all `__init__` signatures match exactly. So the only safe option is to either (have a `default` keyword and use `list.__init__`) or (remove the `default` keyword and use `super` if you so choose).

Comment: If you're inheriting from two classes that both have their own `default` keyword to `__init__`, all is lost; it's not going to work.  Your code will *always* break if another inherited class needs kwargs.  The correct thing to do is to take the parameters specific to your function and remove them from kwargs, and pass the rest on.  (I don't know why you keep saying `super`; `super.__init__(...)` and `list.__init__(self, ...)` in your code are equivalent, except the former will behave in complex MI scenarios where the latter will break.)

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: you seem to be coding for maximum flexibility, I'm coding for YAGNI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it). Shall we agree that both goals are important and therefore the right answer depends on the OP's needs which neither of us really know?

Comment: No.  You you're spreading bad habits to others by showing code like this.  You don't only use `super` when you think it matters; you should be using it by default, all the time, without thinking twice about it.  That's how base methods are called in Python, not by referencing the method directly.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: If you google "glenn maynard class site:stackoverflow.com" you will find lots of examples of classes that lack the call to `super`. If you really want to use super everywhere, then even classes that inherit from `object` need to call `super` in `__init__`. Please practice what you preach.

Comment: Not calling the base `__init__` for classes deriving from `object` is indeed perhaps not ideal practice, but it's definitely typical, idiomatic practice.  Calling base methods directly as you are is *not*; it's wrong, and fixing it to follow the Python data model and Python idiom is trivial: a one-line change for each `list.func`.  I don't know why you're trying so hard to justify not fixing a simple error that will lead others towards bad habits.

Comment: Being a stackoverflow noob, I accepted this reply as an answer, even though it is no better than what I could code myself (in fact, I can think of many aspects of the implementation that I'd prefer to do differently).  I specifically stated that I was interested in something pre-existing (and presumably well-tested) rather than a quick, off-the-cuff implementation...  Next time I'll make this point even clearer.

Comment: Not every class needs to be multi-inheritence friendly, and `super()` has its own problems.  It's up to the programmer to think about the problem, the use, and decide on what's appropriate.

Comment: @unutbu Your `__getitem__` is not checking bounds.  The list should only grow on `__setitem__`, but it is effectively of infinite length the way you have it now.

Comment: @Ethan Furman: `__getitem__` does not check bounds because `DefaultList` is supposed to "autogrow". Do you see a problem with this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: @unutbu My understanding *was* autogrow on setting, not looking.  Rereading the OP's specs, though, I see I was wrong.  That means extra care would have to be taken to allow iterating, or `for item in autogrowing_list: do_something_with(item)` would be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) data structure (1xn matrix).

Comment: isn't that just a dictionary wrapped in an array API?

Comment: There are several implementations: with different storage strategies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857780/sparse-assignment-list-in-python is also a nice example

Answer (score 1):

You could always make a function that handles this:

```
def fillList(item, slot, myList):
    length = len(myList)
    if slot > length:
        augmentation = [item for x in range(slot-length)]
        myList.extend(augmentation)
    else:
        myList[slot] = item
```

Which while not a data structure, does accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea of wheaties's solution and making a prettier interface:

You could inherit from list and overwrite the list '**getitem**(index)' method which maps to [index]  in your class. It should be something like this:

```
class GrowingList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        length = len(self)
        # list is 0 indexed 
        if index >= length:
            tail = [ self.default_value for x in range(index - length + 1)]
            self.extend(tail)


        return super(self.__class__, self).__getitem__(index)
```

This same code can be used if you don't extend the list, but just return some default value on invalid index

This preserves the whole list interface.

Comment: Not sure if it is any more efficient, but your list comprehension could be rewritten as `tail = [self.default_value] * (index-length+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

(This isn't a new answer; just a comment on unutbu's.  It should really be possible to post stuff like this in comments; it isn't, so I have to post it as an answer.)

`CombineListClasses` and `CombineListClasses2` inherit from two classes that both inherit from `list`.  The behavior and doctests are straightforward, but break badly in the original version.

This is all standard practice in Python's data model; you almost never should be calling a base class method directly rather than via `super`.

```
class DefaultList(list):
    """
    >>> x = DefaultList('abc', default='*')
    >>> x
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
    >>> x[6] = 'g'
    >>> x
    ['a', 'b', 'c', '*', '*', '*', 'g']
    >>> x[2], x[4], x[6], x[8]  # should print 'c * g *'
    ('c', '*', 'g', '*')
    >>> x[2:9:2]
    ['c', '*', 'g', '*']

    >>> x = DefaultList()
    >>> x[1] = 'a'
    >>> x
    [None, 'a']

    >>> x = DefaultList(sequence=[1,2,3], default=5)
    >>> x
    [1, 2, 3]
    >>> x[10]
    5
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'default' in kwargs:
            self.default = kwargs['default']
            del kwargs['default']
        else:
            self.default = None
        super(DefaultList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # retrieving an item does not expand the list
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            return [self[elt] for elt in range(key.start, key.stop, key.step)]
        else:
            try:
                return super(DefaultList, self).__getitem__(key)
            except IndexError:
                return self.default

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # setting an item may expand the list
        try:
            super(DefaultList, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        except IndexError:
            self.extend([self.default]*(key-len(self)))
            self.append(value)

# Another class that derives from list:
class AddMethodToList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.value = kwargs['value']
        del kwargs['value']
        super(AddMethodToList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def new_method(self):
        return self.value

# Derive from both classes.
class CombineListClasses(AddMethodToList, DefaultList):
    """
    >>> a = CombineListClasses(default=10, sequence=[1,2,3], value=3)
    >>> a.new_method()
    3
    >>> a[5] = 1
    >>> a
    [1, 2, 3, 10, 10, 1]
    """
    pass

# Derive from both classes in reverse, reversing the call chain order.
class CombineListClasses2(DefaultList, AddMethodToList):
    """
    >>> a = CombineListClasses2(default=10, sequence=[1,2,3], value=3)
    >>> a.new_method()
    3
    >>> a[5] = 1
    >>> a
    [1, 2, 3, 10, 10, 1]
    """
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    print doctest.testmod()
```

Note that in Python 3, this is supported by the language directly:

```
class DefaultList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, default=None, **kwargs):
        self.default = default
        super(self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

but that's not supported in Python 2.  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102

Comment: This post is old enough I may not get an answer here, but is there any reason not to approach default handling like so:  `self.default = kwargs.pop('default', None)`?  I believe that accomplishes the same as your conditional statement with 4 fewer lines of code, but I'm interested more in the proper practice than line count.  If there's a reason not to use `.pop(<idx>, <dflt>)` I'd be interested in knowing.

Comment: @g.d.d.c. Using `kwargs.pop(keyword, None)` is fine, and is the more pythonic solution