# What are the pros and cons of starting indices at 1 or another value

Tags: matlab, indexing, indices

When I have to work on a portion of an array (elements n to n+m of array A), I never know arrays that I produce from this portion of array A (lets call it B) should start at 1 or n. I could either make B 1) range from elements 1 to m-n or 2) range from n to n+m. On a couple of occasions bugs have been produced from me getting this confused.

If memory is a constraint, then 2) wastes elements 1 to n. On the other hand, it is harder to process A and B together if I do 1) and end up needing to use different indices.

What are the benefits of each method when programming in MatLab?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848631/fixing-array-indices-in-python?rq=1) question is related, but doesn't deal with the philosophy of choosing what to do.

Comment: This reminds me of the right-hand vs left-hand traffic when it comes to the rule of the road...

Comment: None other that Edsger Dijkstra (of Dijkstra's algorithm fame) has [a rant](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) on why [zero-based indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) is superior to one-based indexing for computers. I'd guess that his reasoning could be extended to other ranges when one has a choice. Often it is a matter of code readability or minimizing extraneous operations. Don't prematurely optimize.

Comment: Vote to close. The answers to this can be only a prelude to a battle of opinions.

Answer (score 1):

There are benefits to always start array indexes with zero.  While it's a matter of convention, it is a convention that in my experience minimizes error, especially when used in conjunction with closed-below, open-above intervals like `[a, b)`.  The length of such an interval is `b - a`.  Since no `1`s are involved in the expression, I can't forget to put them in.  The interval `[0, length)` is the whole array: again, no need for `1`s.  Offsets like `[x, x + sublen)` also don't need any `1`s.  With 1-based indexing, combining offsets like `x1`, `x2`, `x3` requires careful handling of `1`s.

While some of these features can be obtained in 1-based indexing with closed-above intervals, not all of them can.  When an entire framework adopts the zero-based index, closed-below, open-above convention, like most of C, Python, Java, etc., then you can happily avoid thinking about missing `+ 1` and `- 1` errors in all of your function calls, which is a big help.

I remember having the *choice* to use any base for an index in Fortran (0, 1, -5, whatever).  In the few cases where it was helpful (usually for making indexes symmetric around 0), the same effect could have been achieved by wrapping the array retreival in a function call.  Since those cases almost always involved modelling a continuous variable by a grid, I often wanted to make the grid spacing different from 1 and interpolate between the points, too, and for that I absolutely needed to wrap it in a function call anyway.

I didn't know that Matlab gave you a choice (you're talking about Matlab, right?), but it would make sense, given Matlab's relationship to Fortran.  The above argument has nothing to do with optimization, but if I'm understanding you right and Matlab fills in unused indexes with some kind of placeholder, then zero-based indexing would avoid that, too (as well as bugs associated with unintentionally using the placeholder as though it were real).

Comment: I am using matlab. I don't think matlab does give you the choice of using zero as the start point. It's a shame, because I can see the advantages you describe above. My intended use is a little more limited than what you describe though. If I want to use elements 20 to 30 from array A and put these in array B, should I use elements 20 to 30 in B so that it is compatible with A, or should I use elements 1 to 11? Is that clearer? I don't mean a general rule for all arrays.

Comment: Then is your question about the relative value of using 1 rather than some value greater than 1?  As far as I know, only musicians start counting at 2...

Comment: I always find that I am doing this kind of analysis, say looking at all the data between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m. or something.

Comment: Though I would grumble about the lack of 0-based indexes, I personally would move elements 20 to 30 of A into 1 to 11 of B.  Filling 1 to 19 with placeholders is not just a memory waste--- it's dangerous.  Those fake values could be mistaken for real values without a complaint from Matlab.  At the very least, an array indx error would cause an exception or some sort of interrupt, which would alert you of the error.  Noisy errors are better than silent ones for this kind of work.

Comment: You have a good point. But on the other hand, every time I want to use data from array A or any array like it, I need to use a pointer to start at the right index.

Comment: Wrapping the operation in a function call can help with this sort of organizational problem.  Since you say "every time," you must be doing it often, and that's exactly what functions are for.