# Decomposition function

Tags: python, math

I've been puzzling over how to get a certain function working in Python.  The function itself is like this:

```
(Phi_m)x((n2)) = (Phi_m)(x(m*n + r)) = m*x[n1] + r*(x([n1] + 1) - x[n1])
```

Note:  n here is just to specify some multiple.  It is not a list element, but it becomes a list element when x is applied.  In the below example  For example, we might have that n is larger than any element on the list.  E.g. a list has 9 elements, the largest is 3, and m=1 - here n=9 =/= element of the list.

where n2 and n1 are two different values of an input string, and where n1 is derived by 'decomposing' n2.  We consider `x[0] = 0`, `r` is always at zero or positive and less than `m`, and all values of `n` (either of them) are positive integers. In general functional takes in a string of numbers and outputs another string.  What normally happens is we fix an `m`, say `m = 2`. Now we decompose `n2`. Say `n2 = 5`. Then `F(x(5)) = F(x(2*2+1)) 2x[2] + 1(x[3] - x[2])`.  So if our full input sequence was `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3` we'd have `2*1+0=2`.  So our fifth output term is `2`.

I initially thought to do something like:

```
x = [0,1,1,2,3,3,3,3]

def F(n,j,r,x):
return j * x[n] + r(x[n + 1] - x[n])
for n in range(len(x) - 1):
    print n
```

but this clearly fails for my purposes.

The thing is, for Python to do this it has to know how to decompose each number.  So it knows `2` is fixed, and knows `2*3` is too much and so chooses `2*2`.  Then it has to know this is too little and add remainder `1`.  Only once it's done this can it actually grab `n = 5`.  That is, it can run the function.  It seems clear that once it knows how to do this it can just run through every `n` in our range, but I'm really not sure how to program the meat of this function.

Comment: Isn't a functional supposed to be a map from a vector space to its scalar field? I'm not sure why you want this to output a list of numbers.

Comment: Are you sure `python` is the right tag for this? Are you saying you know how to code this, but you don't know how to code it in Python? Or are you saying you don't know what algorithm to use to code it in any language?

Comment: @user2357112 you are correct I should just call it a function.

Comment: @kojiro I'm not, but I was hoping to program it in Python (it seemed easiest).  I don't in fact know how to program it in any language, though.

Comment: How does the decomposition work? Is it just [divmod](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod)?

Comment: Where do `r` and `n` come from?

Comment: @user2357112 That looks close.  To give another example if we had m=3 and n2=7 we'd want x(3*2+1) to have the function applied to it.  It's essentially decomposing mod j.  r is determined by n2 and j, while n is determined by your input sequence.  So for 12223 you have n=1...5 and then once we apply the function we'll get out another string.

Comment: Okay, we're close to the answer. We just need to make it a bit clearer which of the operations in your equation are multiplication, function evaluation, and list element access. Could you edit your equation to use `[]` for list element access, `()` for function evaluation, and an explicit `*` wherever you want multiplication?

Comment: Definitely, one other thing that might be ambiguous is my notation for the function.  Essentially it takes in all the n2s that it can possibly take in.  So if we have 123 and m=1 we can only get out n=1 n=2 n=3, and more generally we get out one less the number of terms we have since we need the n+1st term to complete the calculations.

Comment: what's the difference between `x(n)`, `x((n))`, `x[n]` and `x([n]+1)` ? I made a guess they were all elements of the same series, but that's not crystal clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how I would decompose a number in the form of `n2 = m * n1 + r`:

```
>>> def decompose(number):
...     # returns a generator of tuples (m, n1, r)
...     for m in range(1, number+1):
...         yield m, number // m, number % m
... 
>>> for m, n1, r in decompose(5):
...     print "5 = %s * %s + %s" % (m, n1, r)
... 
5 = 1 * 5 + 0
5 = 2 * 2 + 1
5 = 3 * 1 + 2
5 = 4 * 1 + 1
5 = 5 * 1 + 0
```

or with a fixed `m`, this is the same as a regular `divmod`:

```
>>> def decompose(number):
...     return number // m, number % m
... 
>>> m = 2
>>> n1, r = decompose(5)
>>> print "5 = %s * %s + %s" % (m, n1, r)
5 = 2 * 2 + 1
>>> m = 4
>>> n1, r = decompose(5)
>>> print "5 = %s * %s + %s" % (m, n1, r)
5 = 4 * 1 + 1
```

or more simply using `lambda`:

```
>>> decompose = lambda number: divmod(number, m)
>>> 
>>> m = 2
>>> decompose(5)
(2, 1)
>>> m = 4
>>> decompose(5)
(1, 1)
```

and now, for a full exanple:

```
>>> decompose = lambda number: divmod(number, m)
>>> 
>>> class Phi_m(list):
...     def __init__(self, items):
...         list.__init__(self)
...         # you need to know at least m numbers.
...         assert len(items) >= m, 'Not enough data'
...         list.extend(self, items)
...     # this is a sparse list
...     # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857780/sparse-assignment-list-in-python
...     def __setitem__(self, index, value):
...         missing = index - len(self) + 1
...         if missing > 0:
...             self.extend([None] * missing)
...             list.__setitem__(self, index, value)
...     def __getitem__(self, index):
...         try:
...             value = list.__getitem__(self, index)
...             if value is not None:
...                 # the item is in the list, yeah!
...                 return value
...             # the item is in the list because it was resized
...             # but it is None, so go on and calculate it. 
...         except IndexError:
...             # the item is not in the list, calculate it.
...             pass
...         print 'calculating Fm[%s]' % index
...         A, B = decompose(index)
...         value1 = self.__getitem__(A)
...         value2 = self.__getitem__(A + 1)
...         print 'Fm[A=%s] = %s, Fm[A+1=%s] = %s' % (A, value1, A+1, value2)
...         print 'back to calculating Fm[%s]' % index
...         # m * x[n1] + r * (x[n1 + 1] - x[n1]) = (m - r) * x[n1] + r * x[n1 + 1]
...         # A = n1 ; B = r ; value1 = x[n1] ; value2 = x[n+1]
...         value = (m - B) * value1 + B * value2
...         self.__setitem__(index, value)
...         return value
... 
>>> x = Phi_m([0, 1, 1])
>>> 
>>> x[5]
calculating Fm[5]
calculating Fm[3]
Fm[A=1] = 1, Fm[A+1=2] = 1
back to calculating Fm[3]
Fm[A=2] = 1, Fm[A+1=3] = 2
back to calculating Fm[5]
3
>>> 
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good idea, the only issue is that it provides decompositions for a variety of m values, which while useful is slightly different from what I'd like it to be able to do.  Ideally m would be fixed from the start and then all future calculations for the input string would be based on the assumption that we live in a world with only that m value.

Comment: Thanks again dnozay.  I'm only hesitating in giving you the accepted answer because @user2357112 seemed like he had planned to answer and I should wait until I can be sure to accept.  That said, I'll definitely mark your answer as useful once I have the reputation to do so!

Comment: Go ahead and accept. I thought you wanted more than this; if the only part that was confusing you was the decomposition, this is a good answer.

Comment: @user2357112 I did in fact want more than this, ideally.  Did you have an idea for implementing the function holistically?  I'm never sure how many other answers I will get though and feel a bit bad not crediting people who have put effort into their responses.

Comment: @dnozay Thanks!  I should mention that one possible issue is that you do not need to know m numbers. For example if m=8 and your string of numbers is 011 (length 3) you can still calculate: 012 since you'll have 1= 8*0+1, 2= 8*0+2.  Another is just that I'm getting syntax errors trying to reproduce your >>> x = Phi_m([0, 1, 1]) example.

Comment: @user2357112 Was this the sort of solution you had in mind?  I'm still a bit wary that the structure is off.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is bugged. At the very least, `__setitem__` isn't setting the item when it should. I never fully figured out which operations were supposed to be what in your post (there are still a bunch of parts where you mix up your notation), and you seemed to indicate you knew where to go once you had the decomposition down, so I figured you'd be able to handle the rest.

Comment: @user2357112 I probably shouldn't have indicated that. I was grateful for a partial answer to help me along the way, but after reading through it more carefully I see that it doesn't really act the way it should (I mentioned this in a second post I made on this topic, I didn't want to crowd this one after having accepted  dnozay's answer).  Would you still be willing to take a shot at it?  This is the other more comprehensive post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677156/decomposing-numbers-and-programming-a-function-in-python-3-2-2

Comment: I made some further edits attempting to fix some of the ambiguity.  I would be happy to answer other questions about it.  I believe all the list and non-list elements are properly indicated though.