# Copying values of a numpy array into specific location of sparse matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

So I am trying to copy values from one numpy array into a sparse matrix. The first array looks like this:

```
results_array = [[  3.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+03]
[  6.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+00   7.00000000e+02]
[  1.60000000e+01   4.00000000e+00   8.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+03]}
```

The second value (or `results_array[i][1]`) dictates the column id, the third value (`results_array[i][2]`) dictates the row id and the fourth value (`results_array[i][3]`) dictates the value of that row, column pair.

So far what I have is this:

```
for i in result_array:
sparse_matrix = csc_matrix((i[3],(i[1],i[2])), shape=(14,14))
print "last array", sparse_matrix
```

The output I get is:

```
File "C:/Users/Andrew/Google Drive/Uni/Final Year/Research Project/Programming/Mine/First UEA/xl_optim/Runestone 2.py", line 13, in <module>
sparse_matrix = csc_matrix((i[3],(i[1],i[2])), shape=(14,14))
File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 48, in __init__
other = self.__class__(coo_matrix(arg1, shape=shape))
File "C:\Users\###\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 182, in __init__
self._check()
File "C:\Users\###\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 219, in _check
nnz = self.nnz
File "C:\Users\###\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 194, in getnnz
nnz = len(self.data)
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

I think I need to create the sparse matrix first and then add the values to it iteratively (I'm imagining something like a `.append` but to a specific location in the matrix) but I have no idea how to create an empty sparse matrix and then assign values to it.

Let me know if you need further clarification.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first element in the tuple you pass to `csc_matrix` needs to be a vector of values, whereas you are passing it an integer. More fundamentally, you're trying to call the `csc_matrix` constructor multiple times in a loop so that it would overwrite `sparse_matrix` on each iteration.

You want to call `csc_matrix` *once* with a vector for each parameter, like this:

```
values = results_array[:, 3]
row_idx = results_array[:, 2]
col_idx = results_array[:, 1]

sparse_array = csc_matrix((values, (row_idx, col_idx)), shape=(14, 14))
```