# Insert object to specific list index

Tags: python, list

How can I add an object to a list at a specific spot in Python? This is what I mean:

I want to add the string `'String2'` to spot *x* in a list, but spot *x* doesn't exist. How can I create spot *x*?

I want it to be something like this:

```
list = ['String1']
x = 4
list.create(x)
list[x] = 'String2'
print(list)
```

Output:

```
['String1', None, None, 'String2']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a sparse list, where values can be entered at arbitrary indices. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857780/sparse-assignment-list-in-python) has some possible solutions, like a custom sparse list implementation or using a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Create your list like this:

```
initial_size = 4
list = [None] * initial_size
list[0] = 'String1'
list[3] = 'String2'
print(list)           # ['String1', None, None, 'String2']
```

To increase size of list / add more spaces:

```
spaces_to_add = 5
list += [None] * spaces_to_add
print(list)           # ['String1', None, None, 'String2', None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with something like this, if you really want:

```
def list_add(list_to_add, data, index):  
if index < len(list_to_add):
    list_to_add[index] = data
else:
    while index > len(list_to_add):
        list_to_add.append(None)
    list_to_add.append(data)
```

Actually, I don't think that this is the best way to do it, you should use a dictionary with integer indexes like this:

```
d = {1: 'String1'}
x = 4
d[x] = 'String2'
```

It is implemented as a hash table, so it has constant lookup times.
Read [this article](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/), about python dictionaries!

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please, fix your error with indexing.

```
x = 4
```

it is not the 4th element, it is the 5th. So you code and result

```
['String1', None, None, 'String2']
```

are not compatible.

And you should keep in mind that linked list is not a C-type array stored as one row in memory. You should initialize the range and values, to construct and use it. Consider as a solution:

```
list = ['String1',None,None,None,None]
x = 4
list[x] = 'String2'
#or (where x - the place where to insert, but not the index!):
#list.insert(x, 'String2')

print(list)
```

Of course you can automate it generating it with lambda or "*".

Other way - to use arrays or dicts, not lists, and in your case it sounds as right idea, but you are asking for help namely with the list.